# Guake/Tilda-like visibility toggle for any application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, window-manager, desktop-customization

[Guake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guake) and [Tilda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilda_%28software%29) are 2 applications in Ubuntu which can be toggled visible/invisible with a hotkey, but this mechanism is built inside of these applications.

Is there some general manager software that allows you to apply this toggling behaviour on any application and set a hotkey for it?

I'm for now only looking to apply it on a Firefox vimperator application instance. But it would be interesting to apply on any other program as well.

Comment: Which window manager?

Comment: I'm using Compiz on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Now yes! I wanted something similar and just added the feature to my little launcher called [marathon](https://github.com/ronjouch/marathon).

Read the documentation: you'll need `wmctrl` and `xdotool`, and the behavior you want is behind the `--toggle` flag.Give it a try and tell me how it goes :)